# How to compile YCM plugin for VIM on Chromebook

Tags: vim, chromebook

I am running a local VIM setup on my Chromebook. When attempting to compile the You Complete Me Plugin I am getting a permission error.

`chronos@localhost ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe $ ./install.sh --clang-completer`
`bash: ./install.sh: Permission denied`

is there an exception flag that can be used to compile the plugin?

Comment: Does your chromebook even have a compiler? But you need to make the shell script executable with `chmod +x ./install.sh`

Comment: I ran it and nothing happened so I am guessing, it gave me permission and was unable to compile. Any thoughts on how I could get the plugin to compile?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Install it with `python install.py`. 
The problem with permission doesn't have anything to to with YCM. You just cannot run `bash`, `sh`, `./`, or `/usr/bin/bash` out of the `/usr/local` directory. If you clone YCM in `/usr/local`, or point Vundle to this path, it should compile with `./install.sh`.

**Note:** You can manage to install vim with python3 support by editing `/user/local/lib/crew/vim.rb`. Changing `depends_on 'python27'` to `depends_on 'python3'` and `--enable-pythoninterp` to `--enable-python3interp` will do the trick. **However**, YCM server will not work on ChromeOS if compiled with `python3 install.py` for yet unknown reasons. I will update this answer if I manage to do it.

Answer (score 0):

After returning to this issue I've decided to go with the Omnicomplete built in VIM feature. I added this to my .vimrc

`set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
 " Move up and down in autocomplete with <c-j> and <c-k>
 inoremap <expr> <c-j> ("\<C-n>")
 inoremap <expr> <c-k> ("\<C-p>")`

So now I just hit `<c-p>/<c-n>` when typing to bring up the autocomplete options, then use `<c-j>/<c-k>` to scroll through the options.

If anyone seeing this has a solution for compiling YCM for VIM on ChromeOS, please post it, that would be a preferable solution.